# which more costly either Session variable or Static model in ASp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Someone told me that always ignore to use **session** in coding due to overload on server..

So i am using **Static model** class for holding value between multiple request...!!!

So is there **static model** is preferable???

Comment: Static model as in 

    public static class MyClass{
       public static string MyValue{get;set;} ?
       ....

Comment: YA!!!@John..
static model is of type Public

Answer (score 1):

Session values are per user.
Static values are per application.

They're not changeable without refactoring code, so be careful to you use them properly.

In terms of cost you must remember to evaluate memory costs and CPU costs. Both increase with the number of concurrent users of the web application if keeped in session variables, and, in addition are dependent on the object complexity, either in static or session approach.

If objects in every user session are the same, then move them to static variables (an application cache).
If objects in the point of view of every user differs, then use the session.

The best solution is rarely pure, but more often mixed.

Answer (score 0):

You must use **session to separate values per user**, and is **good to use static if you have the same values across your program** - and is the same for all user per asp.net pool.

Have in mine.
Static values are the same for all users. Is less costly because they create ones and not use memory allocation, and de allocation every time the program access it, so is a little faster for small values, a lot faster for more amount of data.

Static values are not thread safe and you need to take care of this if you use multithread, or call them on pages with out session.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Plus, static values are lost when the application dies while session values are not necessarily (there a lot of persistent session providers for that).